How to let clangd parser know about standard library files?
I've recently started learning C, and I'm quite new to it. I'm using Neovim, which I'm also quite new to. The issue I have is that the clangd LSP I installed cannot find the standard header files such as stdio.h, which are located in C:\MinGW\include. When I compile it using gcc it works just fine, but I want the errors to disappear so they don't clutter the interface.
I am aware of cmake and compile_config.json files, which I used myself, but as far as I'm aware, these only work at compile time. How can I tell the LSP where the files are located?
I'm on a 64bit Windows device, by the way.

Have a look at https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc, and in particular the paragraph about --query-driver, that tends to be needed with MinGW.

I tried adding this to my compile_commands.json, but it seems to have no effect on the LSP, but compiles just fine. Do I need to add --query-driver elsewhere?

--query-driver is an argument to clangd itself, not an argument in the compile command. It's specified in an editor-specific place. For neovim, see this comment (for lspconfig) or the one above it (without lspconfig). The examples show --log=verbose, but --query-driver=... would go in the same place.
